# Simulate a click with a URL parameter

Tags: javascript, tabs

I am currently working on a page containing 4 different tabs animated/toggleable with Javascript.

I would like to be able to anchor these tabs in order to access a chosen tab depending on a URL parameter.

However, the only way to switch from one tab to another at the moment is to click on it.

Therefore, I assume that an easy way would be to set 4 different URLS of the page.
Eg.

```
pagename.com#1
pagename.com#2
pagename.com#3
pagename.com#4
```

With each number simulating a click on tab 1 to 4.

Can I achieve something like this?

Many thanks,
Geralt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer above states, you can change the hash using `window.location.hash`.  But, if your tabs don't tie in that functionality the active tab won't change just by add/changing the hash.  What you would need to do is in your javascript look at the current hash and determine which corresponding tab/panel to display... Check out this example:

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div><a href="#1">Tab 1</a></div>
    <div><a href="#2">Tab 2</a></div>
    <div><a href="#3">Tab 3</a></div>
    <div><a href="#4">Tab 4</a></div>
</div>

<div id="panels">
    <div id="1">I am a panel 1</div>
    <div id="2">I am a panel 2</div>
    <div id="3">I am a panel 3</div>
    <div id="4">I am a panel 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tabs > div {
    display: inline-block;
}

#panels > div {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // if you want the first one shown...
    window.location.hash = '#1';
    // initially check...
    var h = window.location.hash;
    var panel = findPanel(h);
    if (panel) {
        panelCleanUp()
        $(panel).show();
    }

    $('#tabs').on('click', 'a', function () {
        setTimeout(function () { // let the hash update...
            var hasher = window.location.hash;
            var panel = findPanel(hasher);
            if (panel) {
                panelCleanUp();
                $(panel).show();
            }
        }, 0);
    });
});


function findPanel(hasher) {
    return $('#panels ' + hasher)[0];
}

function panelCleanUp() {
    $('#panels > div').each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

[See the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/av1wtmbu/)

Comment: Sounds exactly what I need! Thanks!
I have tried to update my page with according to your example but I end up breaking the code each time.
Is it workeable in your opinion with such basis: http://jsfiddle.net/72Lk1tfm/ ?

Comment: here, I got it working with your example...The main problem you had was you forgot to include jquery so none of your code was running... http://jsfiddle.net/72Lk1tfm/1/

Comment: If you found this helpful vote it up / make it the approved answer for your question!

Comment: Thanks almightBoognish!
How does the anchor links work in jsfiddle.net/72Lk1tfm/1 ?
Say that I would like the second tab to be toggled on when landing on the page from an external link, how can I do that?

Comment: If you look at the code sample I provided, it explains how to do that...Based on the code in that fiddle, you would just take the li's 'rel' attribute and set window.location.hash to it.  You could then attach an initial checker that looks at the hash and determines which tab to display..

    `var h = window.location.hash;`
    `if (h === 'tab1') {
        // display tab1
    } else if (h === 'tab2') {
        // display tab2
    } else if (h === 'tab3') {
        // display  tab3
    }`

Comment: I have tried to add it to my existing code myself but either it messes up with the tab functionality or it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/72Lk1tfm/2/
I will probably drop it for now as I don't have enough time to get more into it. I am not good enough when it's something more fancy than raw HTML/CSS.
Thanks a lot for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Use `window.location.hash`

```
window.location.hash = "1"; // done!
```

Comment: Sounds like a good plan! Could you explain me a bit how to implement it with my example? I've been on W3schools but I am still a bit confused ...
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Geralt745 you put the thing you want after `#` in place of `1`

Comment: Something like that to get to tab2? http://jsfiddle.net/Lqovgexw/
Sorry, i am pretty confuse with the usage of this function..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @WadeMatveyenko are you crazy?? It is how you stimulate hashes